# Global Mutable array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I wish to be able to access this array in any sub in my secondviewcontroller, were do i add this coding to make it accessible via every sub

```
    NSMutableArray *YoutubeArray;
    YoutubeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property in the interface.

interface (.h file):

```
NSMutableArray *_youtubeArray;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *  youtubeArray;
```

implementation (.m file):

```
@synthesize youtubeArray=_youtubeArray;


//in viewDidLoad/initwith...
self.youtubeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Alternatively, and for more scope Use a [singleton structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like)